# Visual Studio Code adding a package reference for a specific version

Tags: visual-studio, f#

I'm trying to add a reference to FSharp.Data 2.3.2 to a project in Visual Studio Code. Adding with `paket add nuget package FSharp.Data 2.3.2` fails with message:

> Paket version 5.156.7
>
> Performance:
>   - Runtime: 438 milliseconds
>
> Paket failed with
>   -> You cannot use the old and new syntax at the same time:
>   'nuget' is the default argument and must be omitted.

I'm having to use 2.3.2 because the latest version gives error in my one line of code. I tried syntax that works in Visual Studio too: `Install-Package FSharp.Data -Version 2.3.2`, but this just gives me a help page text.

Comment: entire code module t1
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    printfn "%A" "argv"
    0 // return an integer exit code

Comment: error message   error FS3033 : The type provider 'ProviderImplementation.JsonProvider' reported an error : Unable to cast object of type 'ProviderImplementation.ProvidedTypes.ProvidedTypeDefinition' to type 'System.Reflection.IReflectableType'. [c:\a\try1\t1\t1\t1.fsproj]
error FS3033 : The type provider etc etc etc

Comment: Visual studio Code, Intellisense giving me CsvProvider then telling me its not defined, where is it getting the Intellisense from then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the complete documentation for Paket commands on the web site - the  [paket add](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/paket-add.html) page has the information about adding references. The following command works for me:

```
paket add FSharp.Data --version 2.3.2
```